# SQLDeveloper : Not enough arguments

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-spatial

I'm writing an APEX application which utilises spatial for proximity searching via Googlemaps API, I've built the function and it compiles fine, however whenever I try to run it in SQLDeveloper I get the error `not enough arguments`.

The function I created to set the new lat/long point takes one input of postcode from my `stores` table, it then uses the Google map API to return the long lat co-ords for that postcode, which on return builds an `SDO_GEOMETRY` object, which is returned and set in a `location` column in the `stores` table.

Function code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_spatial_point
( 
    -- Only accept postcodes from the store table
    p_postcode stores.postcode%TYPE
)
    RETURN MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY
IS
    -- Build local variables
    l_lng      VARCHAR2(100);
    l_lat      VARCHAR2(100);
    n_spatial_object MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY;
BEGIN
    -- Populate long and lat parameters
    POSTCODE_TO_LAT_LNG_GM_API(p_postcode, l_lat, l_lng);

    -- Populate the new spatial object
    n_spatial_object := MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY
    (
        -- use 01 as we wish to add the point to the map
        2001, 
        -- SRID for WGS84 longitutde/latitude format
        8307,
         -- Set the information of the point ( we don't need a Z co-ord )
        SDO_POINT_TYPE
        (
            l_lng,
            l_lat,
            null
         ),
        null,   -- We have no SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY
        null    -- We have no SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY
    );

    -- Return the new spatial object
    dbms_output.put_line('sdo_gtype='||n_spatial_object.sdo_gtype);
    dbms_output.put_line('first element from sdo_ordinates='||n_spatial_object.sdo_ordinates(1));
    RETURN n_spatial_object;
END set_spatial_point;
```

Why am I getting the not enough arguments error, even when I call it with a valid `stores.postcode%TYPE`, ( I have tried changing to `VARCHAR2` but that doesn't make any difference.)

EDIT:
After creating the function, I run a call to the method:

```
DECLARE
   my_object    MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY;  
BEGIN
  my_object := set_spatial_value('MK80PB');
END;
```

I now get the following error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DECLARE
  my_object    MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY;  
BEGIN
my_object := set_spatial_value('MK80PB');
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 14:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SET_SPATIAL_VALUE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: How are you calling the function, and what is the whole error stack you get back?

Comment: in SQLDeveloper I call `set_spatial_point('PL47PX');` and then run it, which gives me the error.  I'm new to working in SQLDev, how can I see the whole stuck in DBMS_OUTPUT?

Comment: This might not be the source of your problem, but trying to access `SDO_ORDINATES` (in the second `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`) will fail with `ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection`.  This is because, when your code creates `N_SPATIAL_OBJECT`, it specifically sets `SDO_ORDINATES` to `NULL` (and opts instead to use the `SDO_POINT` attribute).  Also, the first two elements of `SDO_POINT_TYPE` are `NUMBER`, but your code is passing `VARCHAR2` values.

Comment: OK, I'll rephrase... can you add to the question everything you run in SQL Developer after creating the function, and all the output you get in the script output window? That should have the ORA-00938 (presumably) but also which line generated the error, which line that as called from, etc.

Comment: @BrianCamire I tried putting `NUMBER` values and also tried to remove the `dbms_ouput` lines, however I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you step into this function in the debugger to determine which function call is throwing the "not enough arguments" exception?

Comment: You can't just call a function, the return value has to go somewhere. Are you assignng a variable in a PL/SQL block? Calling the function in a SQL query? Are you sure you're using Oracle SQL Developer? That message doesn't look right.

Comment: OK, I'm 99% sure you've missed an underscore and it's seeing `set` as a command; so you're doing `set spatial_value('MK80PB');`. That would throw that error in SQL Developer. What do you want to do with the `sdo_geometry` return value? edit: in your PL/SQL block version you seem to be calling `set_spatial_value` but your function is called `set_spatial_point`, which would explain the PLS-00201 you're getting now.

Comment: @AlexPoole I call this in my `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on my store table, its used to take the given postcode and return a spatial object so that I can do some querys on it later, i.e. how many stores are 10 miles from me.

Comment: @AlexPoole doh, you were totally right, very bad typo on my behalf, turned out I was using `set_spacial_value` instead of `set_spacial_point`....embarassing...

Comment: So if you change `set_spacial_value` to `set_spacial_point` are all your errors resolved? If not please edit the question and include the errors you're seeing now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, everything is solved now, can't believe I didn't spot it earlier, thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is obvious: you create the function as SET_SPATIAL_POINT() but you call SET_SPATIAL_VALUE() and that obviously fails since it does not exist.

Now, let's try this out. I had to replace some of your code since I don't have your declarations of the STORES table or the Google call, so I hard-coded the results from that call:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_spatial_point
( 
    -- Only accept postcodes from the store table
    p_postcode varchar2
)
    RETURN SDO_GEOMETRY
IS
    -- Build local variables
    l_lng      VARCHAR2(100);
    l_lat      VARCHAR2(100);
    n_spatial_object SDO_GEOMETRY;
BEGIN
    -- Populate long and lat parameters
    -- POSTCODE_TO_LAT_LNG_GM_API(p_postcode, l_lat, l_lng);
    l_lat:=45.3;
    l_lng:= 3.7;

    -- Populate the new spatial object
    n_spatial_object := SDO_GEOMETRY
    (
        -- use 01 as we wish to add the point to the map
        2001, 
        -- SRID for WGS84 longitutde/latitude format
        8307,
         -- Set the information of the point ( we don't need a Z co-ord )
        SDO_POINT_TYPE
        (
            l_lng,
            l_lat,
            null
         ),
        null,   -- We have no SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY
        null    -- We have no SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY
    );

    -- Return the new spatial object
    dbms_output.put_line('sdo_gtype='||n_spatial_object.sdo_gtype);
    dbms_output.put_line('first element from sdo_ordinates='||n_spatial_object.sdo_ordinates(1));
    RETURN n_spatial_object;
END set_spatial_point;
/
show errors
```

That works fine.

Let's try it out:

```
SQL> select set_spatial_point('XXXX') from dual;
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.SET_SPATIAL_POINT", line 38
```

Again, this is obvious. The error is on line 38:

```
        dbms_output.put_line('first element from sdo_ordinates='||n_spatial_object.sdo_ordinates(1));
```

That fails (obviously again) since n_spatial_object.sdo_ordinates() is null (like you wrote on line 32.

Let's remove those debugging lines and redefine the function. Then let's try it out. It now works as expected:

```
SQL> select set_spatial_point('XXXX') from dual;

SET_SPATIAL_POINT('XXXX')(SDO_GTYPE, SDO_SRID, SDO_POINT(X, Y, Z), SDO_ELEM_INF
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(3.7, 45.3, NULL), NULL, NULL)

1 row selected.
```

Comment: Thanks Albert, I should of closed this, if you check Tue comments I spotted it :) will accept the answer for your effort to answer, thankyou